# Render Only Frames With Marker?

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, video, marker

I am learning how to storyboard. I have set up a video editing project and added a movie file. I am working my way through the movie, marking each frame that is to become a board in a storyboard. What I want to be able to do is render a sequence of images out that are only the frames marked with a marker. I have been searching through the documentation but I can't seem to find a way to do this. Can anyone advise please?

Comment: Seems like you´ll have to make some coding for that one, i haven´t found something to help us.

Comment: Looks like your question has since been answered here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/158364/599 If that answer isn't satisfactory in some way, let me know and we can re-open