# Only render Frames with Markers (one camera only)

Tags: rendering, animation, keyframes, marker

I've been looking for some addon or something to render only the marked frames on timeline, i found this answer here on the stackexchange [Render Videos From Marker Ranges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15372/render-videos-from-marker-ranges)

The thing is this script only works with multiple cameras, i have only one camera that goes all aorund the scene but i only want to render the frames that i've marked on timeline.

Is there someone who can help me modify this script? Or find a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of compilation from various answers (only tested in 2.79):

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

# get existing output path
fp = scene.render.filepath

# set output format to .png
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'

marker_frames = [m.frame for m in scene.timeline_markers]
#print(marker_frames)

for m_f in marker_frames:

    # set marker as current frame
    scene.frame_set(m_f)

    # set output path so render won't get overwritten
    scene.render.filepath = fp + str(m_f)
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) # render still

# restore the filepath
scene.render.filepath = fp
```

Comment: Amazing, it works perfectly on 2.81, also i used freesyle to render and it worked too! Thanks!